# How to make a button not clickable or hide once pressed

Tags: javascript, css, button, cookies

After the visitor subscribes and selects the page, or enters the day after, the subscription button I do not want to show him, because he is already subscribed

Comment: Can you show us [some or your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I use a button with a link to subscribe to the YouTube channel, when pressed it takes it to YouTube

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide it on load and hide it on click

CSS

```
.hide { display:none }
```

Script:

```
var but = document.getElementById("#buttonID");
// sets class onload if localStorage is set
but.classList.toggle("hide",localStorage.getItem("subscribed") != null); 
but.addEventListener("click",function() {
  localStorage.setItem("subscribed","yes") 
  but.classList.add("hide");
})
```

Comment: when the page reloads the class has been removed.

Comment: This statement puts it back! `but.classList.toggle("hide",localStorage.getItem("subscribed") != null); `

Comment: Sorry sir my mistake just added some last touch in testing . good luck in 100k journey

Answer (score 0):

As for security reasons the `:visted` pseudo not support the `display:none` property. The rough answer to this is using `JQUERY` and check if the user already visited and then add the class to it and that class has property of `display:none` working solution below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http:/youtube.com">Subscribe Now</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        localStorage.setItem($this.attr('href'), true);
        $this.addClass('visited');
    });
     $("a").each(function(index, elem){
        var item = $(elem);
        if (localStorage.getItem(item.attr('href'))){
            item.addClass('visited');
        }
    });
    });
```

CSS:

```
  .visited{
    display:none;
  }
```

Comment: enclosed jquery tag with <script></script>

Comment: OP did not tag the question with jQuery. Also where do you hide it after it is clicked and the page is reloaded. Also your code will result in all links on the page will be affected

Comment: just added the new method to check and also when the pages reload

Comment: Your code still will hide and and all links that are clicked on the page